# determine if specific page is in list?

Tags: navigation

It's not hard i think, but i run out of ideas...

In template file I have code like this;

```
$current = $post->ID;
$parent = $post->post_parent;
$pages = get_pages('child_of='.$parent.'&parent='.$parent.'&sort_column=post_title&title_li&hierarchical=0');
$front_id = get_option('page_on_front');
```

I cant figure out how will statement to determine if `$front_id` is in `$pages` array look like !

thx for Your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need to remove, or ignore, it from `$pages`, use the `exclude` argument instead;

```
$pages = wp_list_pages( array(
    'exclude' => get_option( 'page_on_front' ),
    'child_of' => $parent,
    'parent' => $parent,
    'sort_column' => 'post_title',
    'title_li' => '',
    'hierarchical' => '0'
) );
```

I've used `wp_list_pages` as I assume this is the function you've intended to use (`get_pages` does not have a `title_li` argument).

If that **isn't** what you were after, then just loop over the pages to determine if it's there;

```
foreach ( $pages as $page ) {
    if ( $front_is_here = ( $page->ID == $front_id ) )
        break;
}

if ( $front_is_here ) {
    // front page is among pages
} else {
    // front page is *not* among pages
}
```

Comment: the second code example is the answer ^^